# Read from text file only numbers in C

Tags: c, text, numbers

How to read from text file only numbers in C. Except spaces, symbols, enters and letters.

That's how i am reading text:

```
unsigned char symb, symb1;

FileIn = fopen("InCode.txt","rt"); 
while (!feof(FileIn))
    {
       symb=getc(FileIn);
       symb1=symb;
       printf("%c",symb1);
     }
```

This is how it should work:

```
/* Data in the file: */
12hj2 3h23j1

/* Output: */
1223231
```

Comment: @omkant "read in text mode".  As opposed to "rb" read in binary mode.  It's a Windows thing, AFAIK.

Comment: @clintp : Oh thnks actually i have seen first time i did ` man fopen ` but didn't get their also

Comment: Can you post a sample text file, and what you would like to see as the output?

Comment: @Akerlem Based on some of your follow-up comments, I have to ask - are you expecting the program to not read the non-digit characters at all (i.e. just somehow skip over them, even though it can't know that it's not a digit until it reads it)? Unless you have prior knowledge of exactly which characters you want to read, there's no way to do this... The answers posted show how to read every character, but only do something with the ones you want, which is about the best you can do...

Comment: Yes you're right.Program must read only from 0 to 9 and that's all.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this :

```
        char symb ;
        unsigned char symb1;
        FILE *FileIn;
        FileIn = fopen("InCode.txt","rt"); // Haven't checked fopen failure
        while ((symb=getc(FileIn))!=EOF)
            {
               symb1= (unsigned char) symb;  
               if(symb1 >= '0' && symb1 <='9')
                 printf("%c",symb1);
             }
```

If `symb` is between `0` to `9` you print it . And discard all other characters as you mentioned `space`, `newline`, `alphabats` (lower & upper) , any other symbols .

Comment: Try "r" instead of "rt" then see.

Comment: Try `int symb;` instead of unsigned char, or it will fail to detect the EOF.

Comment: @Akerlem : which compiler are you using ?

Comment: @wildplasser : thanks for mentioning it ,how colud I forgot that

Comment: In my program i must using type unsigned char. That's because i have this problem. i'm using visual studio

Comment: `EOF = -1 ` which is defined in `stdio.h` when you use unsigned char then that char is not able to get that `-1` value as the value wrap arounds to `0xff` so you will have to use this

Comment: i know this. But if i using type `int` rest of my program won't work.

Comment: then one thing you can do , create one `unsigned char symb1` and inside the while loop you typecast `int symb `it to `unsigned char symb1` or more if you require and then use symb1 futher.. see my edit

Comment: It's doesn't matter. This is secondary thing. My code still read letters and others.

Comment: @Akerlem : on my gcc 4.5.2 it's working fine , try with `char symb` instead of `int` if you are facing the problem ,It should work.

Comment: I founded where was the problem.

Answer (score 2):

Or you could use `isdigit` from `ctype.h` library.

```
while ( ( symb = getc( FileIn ) ) != EOF ) {
    if( isdigit( symb ) != 0 )
        printf("% c",symb);
}
```

Comment: i tried isdigit. But same thing. Don't know why,but doesn't work.

Comment: I tested the little script, and it worked so, what is the problem, can you be more specific?@Akerlem

Comment: i'm using type `unsigned char`, not `int`

Comment: @Akerlem I made a little modification some minutes ago? Maybe it was so minimal that you didn't notice.